# Extracting elements in dropdown using protractor

Tags: protractor

I am learning protractor f/w for automating Angular Application, currently I am facing difficulty in accessing elements (Action-1, Action-2, ..) from drop down,below is the DOM sample

```html
<div class="actions-menu ng-trigger ng-trigger-showAni" style="top: 97px; left: 1231px; display: block; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);">
        <!----><button class="action-item ng-tns-c11-12 ng-star-inserted" style="">
          Action-1
        </button><button class="action-item ng-tns-c11-12 ng-star-inserted" style="">
          Action-2
        </button><button class="action-item ng-tns-c11-12 ng-star-inserted" style="">
          Action-3
        </button><button class="action-item ng-tns-c11-12 ng-star-inserted" style="">
          Action-4
        </button><button class="action-item ng-tns-c11-12 ng-star-inserted" style="">
          Action-5
        </button><button class="action-item ng-tns-c11-12 ng-star-inserted" style="">
          Action-6
        </button>
      </div>
```

I had tried as below:

```
element.all(by.options('action-item.ng-tns-c11-7.ng-star-inserted')).get(0); 
element.all(by.options('actions-menu.ng-trigger.ng-trigger-showAnimation')).get(0); 
element(by.cssContainingText('.action-item ng-tns-c11-7 ng-star-inserted', 'Action-1'));
```

Can anyone please guide?

Comment: Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Comment: Thanks Simon for reply. Yes,  I tried below                                                                                    
element.all(by.options('action-item.ng-tns-c11-7.ng-star-inserted')).get(0);                   element.all(by.options('actions-menu.ng-trigger.ng-trigger-showAnimation')).get(0);                       
element(by.cssContainingText('.action-item ng-tns-c11-7 ng-star-inserted', 'Action-1'));

Comment: please confirm you have to get options - Action1,Action2,Action 3 ????

Answer (score 0):

Based on html source it can be done similar to this

1. Get table div
2. Get all buttons using tagName and its count inside the div element
3. Loop all button elements to get text inside them

   ```
   it("handling dynamic table",function(){

       var table = element(by.css(".actions-menu.ng-trigger.ng-trigger-showAni"));

       table.all(by.tagName('button')).getText().then(function(txts){
           txts.forEach(function(txt){
              console.log(txt);
           })
       });
   });
   ```